# YYYY-MM-DD has changed to YYYY-DD-MM after moving SQL Server to new domain how do I switch back?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-format

I have moved the domain of my SQL Server and while everything is mainly working the date format for queries seems to have changed.

So if I run this:

```
select convert(datetime,'2012-02-13')
```

I get

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

When I run

```
select @@Language, @@Langid
```

I get

> British | 23

I have tried to set sp_defaultlanguage but this seems to make no difference.

I have also checked the regional settings in control panel and that seems to also be set to British.

Even this code sample causes a problem:

```
set language british

select convert(datetime, '2012-02-13')
```

With the result

> Changed language setting to British.
>   Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows setting do not affect SQL Server parsing dates. There is a server level default language that can be overridden by one set at the login level.

As it stands, [the "safe" format for SQL Server is yyyymmdd](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp) anyway. Try to use that

From [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx)

> Specifies the default language to be assigned to the login. If this option is not included, the default language is set to the current default language of the server. If the default language of the server is later changed, the default language of the login remains unchanged.

For the server, you'd use ["default language" via `sp_configure`](http://sp_configure)

And you can run SET LANGUAGE or SET DATEFORMAT anytime you want of course

Comment: The problem here seems to be that the default language is British but it the database is still using yyyy-dd-mm for some reason.

Comment: no, your *logins* have a different default language. What does the quote in my answer say? Have you read it?

Comment: I have gbn... Sorry I wasn't clear in my comment. I have checked the logins default language and it is also British English.

Comment: @AlexAndronov - In any case, you should always specify the date style on your convert, to avoid this problem. In your case, you should do: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-02-13',120)`

Comment: @AlexAndronov - British English is not the correct language for this format. Check what the login in your old server was using. For me it fails under "British English" but succeeds under "English" or "Simplified Chinese". My guess is that your old login was using US English.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks Martin... That seems to be the answer. When moving the domain the accounts were recreated as default in British English rather than English!